# Как имя файла сделать параметром по умолчанию? PYTHON

Tags: python, файлы, csv

Допустим, что есть какое-то задание, и в конце мне нужно сохранить результат в файл csv. С этим проблем нет, а вот **как сделать имя файла**, куда нужно сохранить результат, **параметром по умолчанию** не понимаю.
Буду благодарна любой помощи.

Вот как я делаю сохранение:

```
FILE_NAME = "FILE.csv"

def save_in_file(FILE_PATH):
    with open(FILE_PATH, "w", encoding="UTF-8"):
        writer = csv.writer(FILE_PATH)
        writer.writerows(he) # he - данные


save_in_csv_file()
```

Comment: `def save_in_file(FILE_PATH="myfile.csv")`  примерно так. Если  правильно понял Вашу проблему

Comment: @Kers ,спасибо, помогли. А вы случайно не знаете как тогда решить проблему с этой строчкой кода writer = csv.writer(FILE_PATH) ? FILE_PATH подсвечивается

Comment: Оформил в виде ответа по идее должно быть что-то такое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```py
def save_in_file(FILE_PATH="default.csv"): # "default.csv" будет по умолчанию
    with open(FILE_PATH, "w", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f) # Тут обьект способный к чтению/записи
        writer.writerows(he) # he - данные
```